# php how do i get access to only parts of a string

Tags: php, powershell, webrequest

I'm working on some php code for a website I code.
I have a PowerShell script from which i want to implement some parts in my php code.

The PowerShell code does a web request and gets back some infos. i save those infos in an object called `$openid`. The line in the PowerShell script:

```
$openid = Invoke-RestMethod ('https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+$($testdomain)+'/.well-known/openid-configuration')
```

I want to use those infos now but only specific parts from it. So I write something like `echo $openid.token_endpoint` because over the object or var called `$openid` I can get access to only parts of it by pressing tab until the part shows up I wanna use. Is that right so far?

So now I'm in the php code.
Php is also doing a web request. I also save those infos php gets back in the var called `$openid` which is a string. the line in my php code:

```
$openid = file_get_contents("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$eingabe/.well-known/openid-configuration");
```

So how can I get this string in an array without hard coding the gaps? Or is there a way to get the infos i want in the same kinda way like in the PowerShell script?

I'm sorry for my english :/ I hope you understand what I wanna explain to u :)

- [PowerShell infos in `$openid`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2aWT.png)
- [Infos I got back from the web request in php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhkT8.png)

Comment: That looks like JSON, so … decode it?

Comment: hi :9 so how do i decode that?

Comment: yeah sry dumb question of me :/ but thanks i think i found the right page.... god dammit im looking for that for around 3 days now :/ :/ :/